How to specify PDA owned by different program in anchor?
Specifying a PDA can easily be done by the following:
#[account(
    seeds = [MY_FST_SEED, MY_SND_SEED],
    bump
)]
pub my_account: Account<'info, MyCoolAccount>,

This makes the PDA be derived using the current program as the program seed though. How can I specify a PDA owned by a different program?

After checking the docs, we find this can easily be done with the seeds::program constraint:
#[account(
    seeds = [THEIR_FST_SEED, THEIR_SND_SEED],
    seeds::program = other_program_pubkey,
    bump
)]
pub their_account: Account<'info, TheirCoolAccount>,

